# Python Remove SOME duplicates from a list while maintaining order?

Tags: python, list, set, duplicates

I want to remove certain duplicates in my python list.
I know there are ways to remove all duplicates, but I wanted to remove only consecutive duplicates, while maintaining the list order.

For example, I have a list such as the following:

```
list1 = [a,a,b,b,c,c,f,f,d,d,e,e,f,f,g,g,c,c]
```

However, I want to remove the duplicates, and maintain order, but still keep the 2 c's and 2 f's, such as this:

```
wantedList = [a,b,c,f,d,e,f,g,c]
```

So far, I have this:

```
z = 0
j=0
list2=[]
for i in list1:
    if i == "c":
        z = z+1
        if (z==1):
            list2.append(i)
        if (z==2):
            list2.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    elif i == "f":
        j = j+1
        if (j==1):
            list2.append(i)
        if (j==2):
            list2.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        if i not in list2:
            list2.append(i)
```

However, this method gives me something like:

```
wantedList = [a,b,c,c,d,e,f,f,g]
```

Thus, not maintaining the order.

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that you want to remove *consecutive* duplicates? Or is there something special about `c` and `f` such that they are treated differently from other elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not completely sure if `c` and `f` are special cases, or if you want to compress consecutive duplicates only.  If it is the latter, you can use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list1
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'c', 'c']
>>> [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(list1)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'c']
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove consecutive duplicates from a list, you can use the following generator function:

```
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(a):
    last = None
    for x in a:
        if x != last:
            yield x
        last = x
```

With your data, this gives:

```
>>> list1 = ['a','a','b','b','c','c','f','f','d','d','e','e','f','f','g','g','c','c']
>>> list(remove_consecutive_duplicates(list1))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore certain items when removing duplicates...

```
list2 = []
for item in list1:
    if item not in list2 or item in ('c','f'):
        list2.append(item)
```

EDIT: Note that this doesn't remove consecutive items

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the desired `wantedList` value for the sample input `list1`.

Comment: You are correct! He want's consecutive 'f's and 'c's preserved... question needs to be more specific (and I need to be less hasty)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
Never mind, I read your question wrong. I thought you were wanting to keep only certain sets of doubles.

I would recommend something like this. It allows a general form to keep certain doubles once.

```
list1 = ['a','a','b','b','c','c','f','f','d','d','e','e','f','f','g','g','c','c']
doubleslist = ['c', 'f']

def remove_duplicate(firstlist, doubles):
    newlist = []
    for x in firstlist:
        if x not in newlist:
            newlist.append(x)
        elif x in doubles:
            newlist.append(x)
            doubles.remove(x)
    return newlist

print remove_duplicate(list1, doubleslist)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to compare this element to the next or previous element

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5
f=6
g=7
list1 = [a,a,b,b,c,c,f,f,d,d,e,e,f,f,g,g,c,c]
output_list=[list1[0]]
for ctr in range(1, len(list1)):
    if list1[ctr] != list1[ctr-1]:
        output_list.append(list1[ctr])
print output_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'g', 'c', 'c']

wantedList = []

for item in list1:   
   if len(wantedList) == 0:
      wantedList.append(item)

   elif len(wantedList) > 0:
      if  wantedList[-1] != item:
          wantedList.append(item)

print(wantedList)
```

1. Fetch each item from the main list(list1).
2. If the 'temp_list' is empty add that item.
3. If not , check whether the last item in the temp_list is
   not same as the item we fetched from 'list1'.
4. if items are different append into temp_list.